# What I meant was... was that correct or not?

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference in meaning among the 3 following sentences?

> What I meant was whether that **is** correct or not.
>
> What I meant was whether that **was** correct or not.
>
> What I meant was whether that **would be** correct or not.

If so, an explanation will be great.

Also is the 1st sentence semantically/grammatically correct? (could using "is" & "was" in the same sentence make the meaning of the sentence ambigous here?)

Comment: Was that question clear? No, it was not.

Comment: You should look through our meta post about [how to write a good title for your question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

> What I was asking was whether...

would be clearer and more idiomatic than **what I *meant* was whether...**

There is no rigid rule that absolutely requires the tense of the *whether*-clause to agree with the past tense in the main clause, though such agreement is good. When it doesn't agree there are consequences.

> What I was asking was whether that's correct or not.  <sup>conversational / colloquial</sup>
>
> What I was asking was whether that was correct or not. <sup>neutral</sup>
>
> What I was asking was whether that would be correct or not. <sup>perhaps a tad more polite than neutral</sup>

Comment: There's also something else you can do. *What I  was asking was, Is that correct or not?"*